# Defining some custom permissions with hook_node_access_records and hook_node_grants

Tags: hooks

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle some custom permissions with Drupal 8, using hook_node_access_records and hook_node_grants.

Here is my setup:

- I have some nodes of type "group". They have a visibility field that is either "public", "community", or "private".
- Other node types have a "group" entity reference field. This links them to a group.
- Users also have a "group" entity reference field. This links a user to a group.

The rules are:

- nodes that are attached to a "public" group can be seen by anyone (including the anonymous user)
- nodes that are attached to a "community" group can be seen by any authenticated user
- nodes that are attached to a "private" group can be seen by users who belong to the same group

For hook_node_access_records and hook_node_grants I have the following (this is based on this blog post: https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/custom-permissions-node-access-grants-drupal-8-and-drupal-7)

```php
function my_module_node_access_records(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  $grants = [];
  $check_access = false;
  // check if the node belongs to a group
  if ($node->hasField("field_group") && $node->get("field_group")->target_id != "") {
    // check the visibility for this group
    $group_visibility = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($node->get("field_group")->target_id)->get("field_group_visibility")->value;
    // build list of users who have access to this group
    switch($group_visibility) {
      case "public":
        // no need to check access, everyone has access to this node
        break;
      case "community":
        $check_access = true;
        // only authenticated user has access
        $users = db_query("SELECT uid FROM users WHERE uid<>0");
        break;
      case "private":
        $check_access = true;
        // only users who belong to this group have access
        $users = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT entity_id as uid FROM user__field_groups WHERE field_groups_target_id=".$node->get("field_group")->target_id);
        break;
    }
  }
  if ($check_access) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
      $grants[] = array(
        'realm' => 'maze',
        'gid' => $user->uid,
        'grant_view' => 1,
        'grant_update' => 0,
        'grant_delete' => 0,
        'langcode' => 'en',
      );
    }
  }
  return $grants;
}

function my_module_node_grants(AccountInterface $account, $op) {
  $grants = [];
  if ($account->id() != 0) {
    $grants['maze'][] = $account->id();
  }
  return $grants;
}
```

So basically for each node I build the list of users who have access to it - depending on which group the node belongs to, which visibility this group has, and whether or not the user belongs to the group

It works well but I have found the following limitations:

1. It creates an exponentially huge node_access table. There is a database row for each node and each user, which seems a bit over the top
2. When a node is saved, the node_access table is automatically rebuilt, which is great. But I need to have it rebuilt when a user is saved too (in case the group field was changed)

So my two questions are:

1. Is there a more efficient approach to achieve what I need?
2. If not, how can I update the node_access table when saving a user?

Many thanks for any idea!

EDIT:

To update the node_access table when saving a user I've done the following:

```php
function my_module_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  // if updating a user and if the groups have changed, we rebuild the node_access table
  if ($entity->bundle() == "user") {
    if ($entity->original && !$entity->get("field_groups")->equals($entity->original->get("field_groups"))) {
      node_access_rebuild();
    }
  }
}
```

That way I only rebuild the node_access table if the groups have changed for that user.

Still wondering if there's a more efficient approach, though...

EDIT 2:

As it turns out, calling node_access_rebuild() doesn't work until I refresh the cache...